# Call dynamic concatenated function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic

I am using user controls (.ascx) that each generate their own specific client validation functions using names like 'validate<%= NameTextBox.ClientID %>'.  I would like to then call these validation functions from a higher level javascript function such as...

```
function checkControl(controlID) {
     //call validate function generated above using controlID 
     // instead of <%= NameTextBox.ClientID %>
}
```

I'd guess the syntax to call a concatenated function name is straight forward but I can't seem to find the answer.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
function checkControl(controlID){
   // create a concatenated function name
   var myfuncname = controlid + '_somethingelse';
   // invoke the function 
   window[myfuncname]();
}
```